# Source Packages will not appear after Java Project creation from existing files in NETBEANS

Tags: java, netbeans

I have downloaded my project from our CVS repo through Netbeans. I've created a "New Project" with those source files. However, Netbeans will not show the source files in the Project View. It will show the build.xml and a "blank paper" icon (where the sources are assumed to have been). I am also getting this error:

"WARNING [org.netbeans.spi.java.project.support.ui.PackageView]: Ignoring source group: org.netbeans.modules.java.freeform.JavaProjectNature$SourceGroupImpl@2060960a with non visible root: ../../../buttercup/src"

I can run a build on the project through Netbeans perfectly. But I just cannot see or edit the files.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but there's no answer and I had the same problem. The "solution" is: Netbeans behaves this way if your project is located in a folder named "CVS" or in subfolder of such a folder. Name your folder different and it should display the sources again.
Why? No idea...